# Can the Way of Mercy monk's Flurry of Healing and Harm feature be used on one target multiple times in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, targeting, healing

With the release of *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, the [Way of Mercy monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayofMercy) has been slightly reworked from the playtest version (in [UA 2020: Subclasses, Part 1](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses01.pdf)). Now I have a question about the new 11th-level feature, [Flurry of Healing and Harm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#FlurryofHealingandHarm-2992676) (p. 50):

> You can now mete out a flurry of comfort and hurt. When you use Flurry
> of Blows, you can now replace each of the unarmed strikes with a use
> of your Hand of Healing, without spending ki points for the healing.
>
> In addition, when you make an unarmed strike with Flurry of Blows, you
> can use Hand of Harm with that strike without spending the ki point
> for Hand of Harm. You can still use Hand of Harm only once per turn.

Can the healing portion of this ability be used on only 1 target?

It doesn't say anywhere in the subclass description that the target can only get healed once a turn; it only says that for the harming side. So can an 11th-level Way of Mercy monk target 1 creature with Flurry of Healing and heal them up to 4 times in the same turn?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here. I'll try to unpack this.

#### Using Hand of Healing as an action.

Hand of Healing says:

> As an action, you can spend 1 ki point to touch a creature and restore a number of hit points equal to a roll of your Martial Arts die + your Wisdom modifier.

If you use Hand of Healing as an action, *you cannot use flurry of blows* because flurry of blows says:

> Immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.

Hand of Healing is not the attack action. Using Hand of Healing in this way allows for a single use of the healing.

#### Using Flurry of Blows

As mentioned previously, using flurry of blows as a bonus action requires that we first use our action to take the Attack action. When we do so, and use flurry of blows, Flurry of Healing and Harm says:

> When you use Flurry of Blows, you can now replace each of the unarmed strikes with a use of your Hand of Healing, without spending ki points for the healing.

This gives us *two* instances of the healing.

#### We can use both instances on one creature.

There is no restriction on using the two instances of healing on the same creature. The important restriction to remember is that *the affected creature must be within your reach*. Hand of Healing requires that you touch the creature you are healing.